# How to use ApiClient.Default.CallApi()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autodesk-forge, rest-client

Looking through the Autodesk.Forge Reference Properties, I have discovered a method called CallApiAsync(), which I would like to use to sent requests such as `GET` the properties of an Autodesk BIM 360 Project.

Below are the parameters that CallApiAsync() uses but can someone explain what each of them are and how I can `null` the parameters I don't need?

```
CallApiAsync(string path, 
             RestSharp.Method method, 
             System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> queryParams, 
             object postBody, 
             System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> headerParams,
             System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> formParams,
             System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, RestSharp.FileParameter> fileParams, 
             System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> pathParams, 
             string contentType)
```

Comment: You can check the source for this here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/src/Autodesk.Forge/Client/ApiClient.cs#L218 but probably you are not going to use this directly, instead you will use another method that call this one, like this https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/ProjectsApi.cs#L496

Comment: Thanks for the source code, after using a couple of code I was able to get my method to work as expected from the CallApiAsync() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/2b68083e7f3de63ef84cd4499ef0ab5d43bbc4fc/src/Autodesk.Forge/Client/ApiClient.cs#L122) it doesn’t really check for null or fall back to any default value so you will need to provide an empty value for the args you don’t need, such as

```
 CallApiAsync(“Your:Api/path/”, Method.GET, new Dictionary<string,string>(), new {}, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the source code, it was very helpful in creating the structure for the CallApi function.